# Union of object vs Union of pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have two union-line structs:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    union {
        vector<int> vi;
        vector<double> db;
    };
};
```

and

```
struct B {
    union {
        vector<int> * vi;
        vector<double> * db;
    };
};
```

I understand that I have to work with them differently, for example:

```
A a;
new (&a.vi) vector<int>;
```

vs

```
B b;
b.vi = new vector<int>();
```

Beside that, are there any advantages to using the first approach (`unrestricted union`) to the second one (just holding pointers to current vector)? Or are they functionally and performance-wise identical and only thing different is how I work with them?

EDIT: original code was minimalistic example which didn't compile, I added `A() {}` and `~A() {}` in A struct to make it correct and compile-able.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with approach 1?

Comment: yeah, this code doesn't compile, I know, it's just example to illustrate what I mean. Adding `A() {}` and `~A() {}` should make it correct.

Comment: BTW: If your question is not only for language learning but for real use, you must have an idea how to use such kind of unions. The receptor must distinguish between the different content of the unions. And if you need additional hand crafted type info and write your own switch/if in every method, you should think again of your design.

Comment: @Klaus This union is part of parsing code which can read array of various types from file base on metadata. Each receptor goes for the same field (vector) every time, union is used only to enable on parsing function to handle all types. Only `switch` in my design is two methods, one constructs correct vector (eg. `new (&a.vi) vector<int>;`) and one which deletes it (eg. `a.vi::~vector<int>();`). Does that seem reasonable to you?

Comment: I prefer defining a base class and derived types which do the same job, but in an OOP version. Your parser can generate correct objects with `Base* = new ... ` where the objects from the type DerivedX/DerivedY ... With virtual destructors your code exactly can do what you want. All algorithms which must deal with your data can be written in virtual methods. After creation of your data objects no hand crafted switch/if is needed any more.  Look for `Factory Pattern` and `Serializer`, eg. `boost::serialize` or `google protocol buffers`

Answer (score 3):

> I added `A() {}` and `~A() {}` in `A` struct to make it correct and compile-able.

Adding a constructor and a destructor made your code compileable, but it did not make it correct. The problem inherent in the original example remains: the compiler does not know how to handle memory behind your `union`.

Both vectors manage their own memory. `vi` manages pointers to `int`, while `db` manages pointers to `double`. Both vectors are placed in the same spot in memory, so their pointers are shared. When it is time to assign, copy, or destroy `A`, the compiler has no idea whose functions to call - `A::vi`'s or `A::db`s.

Although you can probably make it work by defining all special functions for resource management (constructors/copy constructors/move constructors/destructors) this is a non-trivial exercise that leads to a very fragile code. The problem is that the code would have to change every time you add a new member to the `union`, but the compiler has no way of alerting you to it. The old code would compile, but it would cause undefined behavior as soon as you assign your new member and copy the union containing it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the differences between using values or pointers are that if you use pointers you have to manage ownership. Having a member means that the member class will take care of its destruction automatically in the destructor and of copying in its copy/move constructor and assignment operators.

However when using *unrestricted unions* the compiler won't generate the [special member functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions) for those functions which are non-trivial in the union's members.

In the case of `std::vector` these include pretty much **all** the the special member functions.

This means that you will have to define these functions yourself whether you're using members (since the compiler won't do it for you) or pointers (since the default ownership of pointers is not what you want if you used `new`).

The obvious difference is whether the member resides on the heap in a separate allocation or in the object itself, this is probably less important with `vector`s since most of the object will reside on the heap anyway.

Personally I would avoid using *unrestricted unions* unless I had a very good reason, saving the space of one `vector` (three pointers) is probably not good enough reason.